# SPA - Should servers http cache be turned off for all pwa related resources?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Should any of PWA related resources be served with any kind of cache headers from server or should we move classic http caching out of our way by turning it completely off?

Namely, what should be http cache headers for:

1. **manifest file**

   Related to it, how does new versions of manifest file (favicon changed for example) get to the client?
2. **service worker js** file
   (this one is a bit tricky because browsers check for new versions every 24 hours so some caching might be good?)
3. **index.html** (entry point for spa)

My understanding was that it should be turned off completely and all the cache should be handled from service worker but there seems to be different infos out there and hard to extract best practices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's some guidance at https://web.dev/reliable/http-cache, along with a number of other resources on the web.

In general, building a PWA and introducing a service worker doesn't change the best practices that you should follow for your HTTP caching.

For assets that include versioning information in their URL (like `/v1.0.0/app.js`, or `/app.1234abcd.js`), and you know that the contents of a given URL won't even change, you should use `Cache-Control: max-age=31536000`.

For assets that don't include versioning information in their URL (like most HTML documents, and also `/manifest.json`, if you don't include a hash there), you should set `Cache-Control: no-cache` along with `ETag` or `Last-Modified`, to ensure that a previously cached response is revalidated before being used.

For your service worker file itself, modern browsers [will ignore the `Cache-Control` header](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/fresher-sw) value you set by default, so it doesn't really matter. But it's still a best practice to use `Cache-Control: no-cache` so that older browsers will revalidate it before using it.

Comment: thank you very much for this answer! could you please verify just one more detail: should `manifest.json` be cached in service worker or should it be left without any cache? (for the purpose of changing app name, favicon, etc) or should cycles for those kind of changes be controlled by `serviceworker.js` file itself so that if new versionis detected new manifest will also be fetched from server? in short: how to ensure reliable manifest file related changes?

Comment: You should cache `manifest.json` within your service worker. You need to have some sort of strategy in place for ensuring that all of your unversioned URLs that you end up caching in the SW get updated eventually—something like https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching can help if you want to cache them in advance, or something simpler, like https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/offline-cookbook/#on-network-response

Comment: (i know this might go out of scope of single question but i will end up with this one) does change for favicon, e.g., in manifest file of app already added to homescreen shows up a change or should it be re-added to homescreen? (yes/no is enough and i am accepting your answer) thanks a bunch, you’ve cleared a lot of dilemas on my side!

Comment: Please see https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/integration/webapks#update-webapk